# <%# Eval("") %> in href prefixes relative path in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, anchor, eval, relative-path

I have an `.aspx` in which there is one anchor tag whose `href` property is set by the server side code i.e. `DataTable`.

My site url is : [xxx/Pages/Home.aspx] and suppose the href from the `DataTable` is bound http://www.google.com then the link redirects to [xxx/Pages/http//www.google.com] instead of http://www.google.com . Somehow it prefixes relative url of page.

My `ascx` file is :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:ListView ID="Feed" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="Main">
                        <div class="Ttile">                                                     
                            <a href="<%# Eval("Link") %>" target="_blank" title="<%# Eval("Title") %>" ><%# Eval("Title") %></a>                           
                        </div>                          
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to redirect the user to http://www.google.com when user clicks on the link but the anchor tag redirects to `http://xxx/Pages/http//www.google.com`

If I put `<%# Eval("Link") %>` outside the anchor tag then it displays the proper url like : http://www.google.com. It means the data in "Link" column is perfect

How should I tackle this issue?

Comment: I want to redirect the user to http://www.google.com from the anchor tag. But somehow it prefixes server relative Url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
 <%# RemoveServerUri(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Link")))
```

**C#**

```
           public string RemoveServerUri(string link)
    {
            link = link.Replace("xxx/Pages/", "");
            return link;
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to prefix xxx/Pages before the "Link". It automatically prefixes

Comment: Thanks for answering sir, should I put the `<%#RemoveServerUrl....%>` in `href` property?